# Finding Java packages in Linux

Tags: java, ubuntu, package, classpath, paho

I've only used Java previously on Windows using the Eclipse IDE. I would add packages by adding .jar files on the user interface.

I am using Ubuntu now and have installed the Java Paho MQTT client : https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java.git.

On my system, there is then a folder called paho.mqtt.java which has all the code inside.

However if I create a simple test.java application inside this folder which uses the paho packages and try to compile it with javac, I get errors such as

```
error: package org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3 does not exist 
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient;
```

The org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3 for folder for example is on the same level as my test.java file, so why can't it find it? I've also explicitly added to CLASSPATH the full path to the paho.mqtt.java folder which contains all these packages, but it still doesn't work. Perhaps i'm missing something obvious, but I can't see it.

Comment: Make your life easier and use maven and a IDE like IntelliJ and Eclipse. A programer should not be bothering about such "low-level" problems

Comment: @GhostCat Yes there are .java source files within the directory. There are no JAR files.For example, inside paho.mqtt.java, There are a number of directories with the same names as the packages that i'm trying to import.. example org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3 directory exists with all the source files etc. Yes javac works.

Comment: @Lino I'm using an embedded computer computer tho. No UI

Comment: @Engineer999 Then I suggest making your life easier by using a ubuntu with an UI, unless of course you can't / are not allowed to

Comment: @Lino The thing is: we dont understand his use case. If the goal is to simply RUN something from a linux machine, then the whole approach is already broken. Then he should think how to build and create something that DEPLOYS to a linux system.